# Facebook graph API search https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=query&type=user with two keywords

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

If I perform a Facebook graph api search such as:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=query&type=user
```

Where query is just one word such as 'Mark' , everything is fine and there are results.
However if query is two words such as 'Mark Roberts' , there are no results returned.

I have tried using 'Mark+Roberts' and also tried using URL encoding with escapes but this does not help. However when I use two keywords and remove the &type=user, I get results (albeit a large amount of random facebook stuff).

So:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user   < WORKS

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark+robers&type=user   < DOES NOT WORK

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark+robers  < WORKS (but does not return people)
```

Has anyone run into this issue?

Facebook do not seem to mention anything about this : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/

NOTE: I am doing this of course with an authenticated APP ID and logged in user etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested with web browser and it works as expected.

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Did you do this with an app access token or a user access token?

Comment: it's a user access token, and you can reproduce on graph API explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dmark%20robers%26type%3Duser

Comment: Strangely the exact same call with an access token I get through the iOS SDK returns an empty array as I described.. Do you know why this may be? The access token I am using is also a user token I believe.

Comment: @Zigglzworth The app access token is quite short, such as 43 characters. However the user access token is obviously longer, such as 212 characters.

Comment: @Zigglzworth Can you try to use the access token you get from iOS SDK, and put inside https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dmark%20robers%26type%3Duser ?

Comment: I can't understand this token thing.. The search above worked for me all of the sudden though I didn't change anything but then when I try to access https://graph.facebook.com/[FB_USER_NAME]/photos I get "A user access token is required to request this resource." My token is long (around 250 chars)..

Comment: Solved but not exactly sure how .. ticked your answer :)

Comment: You should create a new question for photo issues and provide more detail about it. Ok, thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible to further narrow down the user search with location or work something like that ?

Comment: @NikhilGeorge possible but impractical, e.g https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3D%E6%9E%9C%E7%9A%9E%26type%3Duser%26fields%3Dwork&version=v2.4 , your access token unlikely have enough permissions to see this fields.

Answer (score 0):

The search according to "type=user" is deprecated now. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4